# how to bring up an alarm sound chooser

Tags: android

I have found out how to bring up a ringtone chooser with...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
startActivityForResult( intent, 999);
```

...but can not find the equivalent for choosing the **alarm** sound. Is it a similar method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your flag ([`ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER)) combine with [`EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE) and [`TYPE_ALARM`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#TYPE_ALARM). Hope it helps  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a mp3 from the sound card by setting the info in the intent like:

```
intent.putExtra("Ringtone", Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/audiofile.mp3"));
```

Comment: That's useful information - but not really answering the question.